# QGIS 3.22.16 Split road lines at polygon border

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, clip, splitting

I am using the QGIS 3.22.16. I tried to get the length of the roads in each county. I used the clip tool however the road length of the ones crossing the boundary still the same length. By any chance is there a tool or method that will give me the exact length. I was thinking of a tool that will split the lines at polygon. So I can get the exact length for each road. For example, one road before the clip measures 2145 meters. After the clip, the road is cut but the length still the same in the attribute table. According to the measure line tool the length is 1523 meters.

Comment: the attribute table is not automatically updated, you would have to (re)compute the length of each segment after the split

Comment: if you want to calculate new length of the lines, update the existing field with the $length function on the field calculator.

Comment: Before recalculating as suggested in previous comment make sure that the road length in the attribute table is the same as the segment length (geometry length). it happen that the attribute table record "real world length" (taking into account elevation and any curve as it would be measured by an odometer) while the segment are a simplified representation and will likely have a shorter and less accurate length....

Comment: Instead of clipping your roads one by one for each county, you could run an Intersect.  There is a calculate geometry plugin which you could use to calculate lengths after the intersect.

Comment: How are you getting the length? There are many ways of doing so in QGIS.

Comment: Intersect road and polygons. Recalculate length field